# Printing a directory containing spaces

Tags: r

I have the following print statement:

```
stat <- paste("scp /home/owner/run2/reports/", x, "_EC.zip /home/adam/Desktop/Link\ to\ Software\ Project/Experiments/exp_20/run2/results/", sep = "")
```

When I print the statement `stat`, I get the following result:

```
scp /home/owner/run2/reports/modelTable_EC.zip /home/adam/Desktop/Link to Software Project/Experiments/exp_20/run2/results/
```

As you can see the part `Link\ to\ Software\ Project` is printed without the `\` symbol which is needed when I use this path in the terminal (ubuntu terminal).

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: [`shQuote`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/shQuote) for each file/directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want that to work in terminal you can put the problematic path in (single) quotes.

```
x <- "modelTable"

stat <- paste("scp /home/owner/run2/reports/", x, "_EC.zip '/home/adam/Desktop/Link\ to\ Software\ Project/Experiments/exp_20/run2/results/'", sep = "")
## Using cat prints it without the extra quotes
cat(stat)
## scp /home/owner/run2/reports/modelTable_EC.zip '/home/adam/Desktop/Link to Software Project/Experiments/exp_20/run2/results/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you consider a command-line as a sequence of command and arguments vice a long string. R's `system` does you no justice here, and `system2` is barely better: while it encourages thinking of a command as a vector of its components (be they command, hyphen-arguments, or files/paths), it just naïvely concatenates the strings without consideration for shell-quoting or what-have-you.

I deal with it defensively, using `shQuote`. The good thing is that it will work on files/paths even if they don't need it, so you cannot effectively over-use it. (There is typically no need to use it with hyphen-arguments, but some tools (many?) don't care and work anyway, so technically

```sh
$ ssh "-v" "/home/owner/..." "/home/adam/Desktop/..."
```

should work just fine in a shell.

So, `shQuote` anything that resembles a path. (I say "resemble" with the assumption that things are formed programmatically ... static arguments don't strictly need it, even though as I said before it should not hurt to do so.)

```r
cmd <- c("scp", shQuote(paste0("/home/owner/run2/reports/", x, "_EC.zip")),
          shQuote("/home/adam/Desktop/Link\ to\ Software\ Project/Experiments/exp_20/run2/results/"))
cmd
# [1] "scp"                                                                             
# [2] "\"/home/owner/run2/reports/modelTable_EC.zip\""                                  
# [3] "\"/home/adam/Desktop/Link to Software Project/Experiments/exp_20/run2/results/\""
```

To print it to the console such that you can copy it and paste it into into a terminal/shell:

```r
cat(paste(cmd, sep = " "), "\n")
# scp "/home/owner/run2/reports/modelTable_EC.zip" "/home/adam/Desktop/Link to Software Project/Experiments/exp_20/run2/results/"
```

Or you could just run it from R directly:

```r
system2(cmd[1], args = cmd[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

a simpler reproducible example

```
x <- "modelTable"
stat <- paste0("reports/", x, "_EC.zip /home/link\ to\ Software\ Project/Experiments/")
> stat
[1] "reports/modelTable_EC.zip /home/link to Software Project/Experiments/"
```

Can you use "/"?

```
stat1 <- paste0("reports/", x, "_EC.zip /home/link/ to/ Software/ Project/Experiments/")
stat1
#[1] "reports/modelTable_EC.zip /home/link/ to/ Software/ Project/Experiments/"
```

Else escape the escape `\` symbol

```
stat2 <- paste0("reports/", x, "_EC.zip /home/link\\ to\\ Software\\ Project/Experiments/")
stat2
#[1] "reports/modelTable_EC.zip /home/link\\ to\\ Software\\ Project/Experiments/"
```

Comment: Using `/` is not an option. The second answer is almost there, you need to use `cat` in order to get a result that can be copied directly to the terminal.

Comment: Why is `/` not an option? I use R on linux and windows and use `/` equally on both.

Comment: @r2evans It is ok to use it as folder separator, but it does not escape spaces

Comment: Oh, huh. That's weird, I didn't see that that is what he was using them for here. Yeah, not right.