# Error in system(command, intern = TRUE) : '“C:\Program' not found selectWeka function

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the code below from BioSeqClass package, however I get an error message:
Error in system(command, intern = TRUE) : '“C:\Program' not found

selectWeka(data, evaluator="CfsSubsetEval", search="BestFirst", n)

Comment: Probably solved with hints from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56301938. Namely, add quotes, either programmatically (preferred) with one of `shQuote`, `dQuote`, `sQuote`; or manually around the program path/name.

Comment: And ... looking at the [source](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages//2.10/bioc/html/BioSeqClass.html), this is definitely a bug in the Bioconductor's package: they use `system` without protecting the arguments (as per my previous comment). Since their mirror on github is defunct (no longer found), I don't know how you can submit an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with how `BioSeqClass` is calling java: it is leaving the file names unprotected/unquoted, and R's `system` and `system2` commands are horrible by not forcing quoting. (If you ever think of using these commands directly yourself, I strongly recommend something like [`processx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/processx/index.html).)

One *should* create an issue or bug-report, but I don't know how to do that with Bioconductor, and their mirror on github (https://github.com/Bioconductor-mirror) is defunct, so I'm at a loss there. Hopefully somebody with more info can weigh in on this.

---

### Workarounds

It is not obvious if the problem is due to where `weka.jar` is located or perhaps one of the other arguments. You can find out where the problem is by debugging the `selectWeka` function and inspecting the value of `command` before the system call. Look for the `Program Files` component of a path.

If the problem is with `weka.jar`, then this suggests that you are installing packages somewhere under `C:\Program Files\`, which is in my experience bad practice on two counts:

1. For many problems I cannot recall (but this one re-ignites the discussion), I never install R in the default location under `C:\Program Files\...`; instead, I install it under a new directory, `C:\R\R-3.5.3` (version-based) and go from there. You may not have control over this if on a university/company system.
2. Since this is not in a base-R package, this suggests that either you are not using a personal library location (collection of packages), or have placed your personal library for some reason under `C:\Program Files`. If the former, I strongly suggest you never install new packages inside the base-R installation directory, instead using your own. See `?.libPaths` and many other tutorials/discussions on the topic online. Using `packrat` or `checkpoint` might also mitigate this problem.

If the problem is with `trainFile` (if I'm reading the source correctly), then your "permanent" fix is to change where Windows puts temporary files, as this `trainFile` is a temporary file created specifically for this function-run. If this is your problem, I'll leave it up to you to fix.

Regardless, you may not have time or need to make a more permanent solution, you just want to run this once or twice and then move on. For that fix:

3. Again, `debug(selectWeka)`, and once `command` is defined (the next command to be executed is `tmp <- system(command,intern = TRUE)`), run this code to fix the value of `command`:

   ```r
     if(search=="Ranker"){
         command = paste("java -cp ", shQuote(file.path(.path.package("BioSeqClass"), "scripts", "weka.jar")),
                         " weka.attributeSelection.", evaluator, " -i ", shQuote(trainFile),
                         " -s \"weka.attributeSelection.", search, " -N ", n, "\"", sep="" )
     }else{
         command = paste("java -cp ", shQuote(file.path(.path.package("BioSeqClass"), "scripts", "weka.jar")),
                         " weka.attributeSelection.", evaluator, " -i ", shQuote(trainFile),
                         " -s weka.attributeSelection.", search, sep="" )
     }
   ```

   (For the record, all I changed was adding `shQuote` twice to each `paste`.) Confirm that `command` now has quotes around things, something like

   ```r
   Browse[2]> command
   [1] "java -cp \"C:\\Program Files\\...\\weka.jar" weka.attributeSel... -i \"c:\\path\\to\\some\\tempfile\" ...
   ```

   Then you can continue-out of the debugger and let it run its course.

   (I hope you don't have hundreds of calls to `selectWeka`.)

Caveat: I am not a use of `BioSeqClass`, so I'm saying all of this from speculation and inference. I might have mis-located the source of the error. And since I don't know what I'm doing with it, I have not tested the modified `command` assignment within `selectWeka`. I believe `shQuote(...)` is the right way to go, but you might need to use `sQuote` or `dQuote` instead, I'm not sure how your system is setup.